# OpenSSL Bio_gets in client

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I'm trying to implement a simple SSL client with OpenSSL, but I want to read only a single line with `BIO_gets()`. I got a working test program based on the client example here:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_new_ssl_connect. 
But in this code the function `BIO.read()` is used. I tried it by just replacing BIO.read with BIO_gets, but in this case -2 is returned and according to the documentation this operation is not implemented in the specific BIO type. I know that the BIO in the example is an SSL BIO and in the server example (Which is using BIO_gets) a buffering BIO is on top of the SSL BIO:

```
bbio = BIO_new(BIO_f_buffer());
sbio = BIO_push(bbio, sbio);
```

I tried to put the above two lines in my client code, but then the program freezes. So my question is: How can I use BIO_gets in my client program to read one line at a time?

**Full code:**

```
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    SSL_library_init();

    context = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    if(SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(context) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Error: Can't load default verify paths!\n");
        printf("Reason: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        return -1;
    }

    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(context);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);

    if(!ssl){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't locate SSL pointer\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Don't want any retries
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);


    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, connection);

    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Error: Can't load default verify paths!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid certificate!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    static char recv_buffer[1024]; 

    // Read line
    int len = BIO_gets(bio, recv_buffer, 1024);
    printf("Received: %d, %s", len, recv_buffer);

    return 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide your full code?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it as follows:

This creates the new buffered BIO

```
BIO *bbio = BIO_new(BIO_f_buffer());
```

Now you have to chain it to your existing SSL BIO

```
BIO_push(bbio, bio);
```

and then you can call `BIO_gets()` on this

```
int len = BIO_gets(bbio, recv_buffer, 1024);
```

which reads a single newline-terminated string similar as `fgets()` does from a file stream.

This should work as you expect.

Comment: I tried this already. When I do this the program freezes at `int len = BIO_gets(bio, recv_buffer, 1024);`

Comment: @Quentin Where do you connect to? What is your peer?

Comment: @Quentin btw. what you wrote above is different from what I propose here. Did you try it _exactly_ as I write?

Comment: I got it now. Strangely when I override the ssl bio with the buffer it's not working `bio = BIO_push(bbio, bio); BIO_gets(bio, recv_buffer, 1024);`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, and the fix is obvious only in retrospect.

TL;DR: BIO_gets is hanging because the server isn't sending any data.  It's not sending data because **the data sent in the initial BIO_write is still sitting in the buffer BIO**.  Call BIO_flush after your write to get it out of the buffer, into the socket, and over the wire.

Caveat - I strongly suspect that your code sample is incomplete, and specifically that it is missing a BIO_write or BIO_puts.  If not, and your server truly is sending data unprompted as soon as a socket opens, then this answer probably doesn't apply.

Maybe your code evolved like mine.  I had something working, decided I wanted to use BIO_gets, and slapped a buffer on there without doing too much reading - or thinking, for the matter.  Naturally buffers work both ways.